# Go Get OAuth2 Giving Me Weird Errors on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, go, google-oauth, linux-mint

Attempting to follow along with https://jacobmartins.com/2016/02/29/getting-started-with-oauth2-in-go/

When I run `go get golang.org/x/oauth2` nothing weird comes up, but when attempting to run the code using `go run main.go`

I get the following in my terminal:

```
# google.golang.org/grpc/credentials
../../../google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/credentials_util_pre_go17.go:58:32: error: reference to undefined field or method ‘GetCertificate’
   GetCertificate:           cfg.GetCertificate,
                                ^
../../../google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/credentials_util_pre_go17.go:69:32: error: reference to undefined field or method ‘ClientSessionCache’
   ClientSessionCache:       cfg.ClientSessionCache,
                                ^
../../../google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/credentials_util_pre_go17.go:72:32: error: reference to undefined field or method ‘CurvePreferences’
   CurvePreferences:         cfg.CurvePreferences,
                                ^
../../../google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/credentials_util_pre_go17.go:58:3: error: unknown field ‘GetCertificate’ in ‘tls.Config’
   GetCertificate:           cfg.GetCertificate,
   ^
# golang.org/x/net/http2/hpack
../../../golang.org/x/net/http2/hpack/huffman.go:14:20: error: reference to undefined identifier ‘sync.Pool’
 var bufPool = sync.Pool{
                    ^
../../../golang.org/x/net/http2/hpack/huffman.go:14:24: error: expected ‘;’ or newline after top level declaration
 var bufPool = sync.Pool{
                        ^
# golang.org/x/net/context/ctxhttp
../../../golang.org/x/net/context/ctxhttp/ctxhttp_pre17.go:36:5: error: reference to undefined field or method ‘Cancel’
  req.Cancel = cancel
     ^
# golang.org/x/oauth2/jws
../../../golang.org/x/oauth2/jws/jws.go:75:17: error: reference to undefined identifier ‘base64.RawURLEncoding’
   return base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(b), nil
                 ^
../../../golang.org/x/oauth2/jws/jws.go:93:16: error: reference to undefined identifier ‘base64.RawURLEncoding’
  return base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(b), nil
                ^
../../../golang.org/x/oauth2/jws/jws.go:113:16: error: reference to undefined identifier ‘base64.RawURLEncoding’
  return base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(b), nil
                ^
../../../golang.org/x/oauth2/jws/jws.go:124:25: error: reference to undefined identifier ‘base64.RawURLEncoding’
  decoded, err := base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodeString(s[1])
                         ^
../../../golang.org/x/oauth2/jws/jws.go:151:41: error: reference to undefined identifier ‘base64.RawURLEncoding’
  return fmt.Sprintf("%s.%s", ss, base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(sig)), nil
                                         ^
../../../golang.org/x/oauth2/jws/jws.go:174:33: error: reference to undefined identifier ‘base64.RawURLEncoding’
  signatureString, err := base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodeString(parts[2])
```

Go version is go version xgcc (Ubuntu 4.9.3-0ubuntu4) 4.9.3 linux/amd64

Running Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you placing your `main.go`? Are you following go lang project structure as mentioned here - https://golang.org/doc/code.html ?

Comment: main.go is inside my home directory under projects/golang/github.com/user/rental_api. gopath is set to the projects/golang folder, and goroot is /usr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using go cgo installation. On Linux mint `golang-go` seems to be the distribution name.

But I would suggest installing the latest version of `go` (or version go 1.5 atleast) as mentioned in the below link and try again.

https://golang.org/doc/install

Remove your current installation before proceeding with the `golang-go` installation.

Comment: Uninstalled go by removing usr/local/go, removed references to go lang env variables in .profile & .bashrc, reinstalled latest version of go from the golang.org downloads page...still get the same output when running 'go version' -- when using go env I get GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/gccgo/tool"...should I uninstall and use sudo apt-get install golang-go?

Comment: I would suggest install go from golang.org.Add the location of installation directory in GOROOT. Add GOROOT in your PATH env variable. Also make sure the `cgo` installation is not in your `PATH`.

Comment: sorry it took me months  select - i thought i already selected you